# Intersection points of two trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry

I am studying for a SAT II Math2C and I came across this question in Barron's book.

Solve $2 \sin(x) + \cos2(x) = 2 \sin^2(x) - 1$ [$0\le x \le 2\pi$]

The solution says put the equations in a calculator and you'll get the intersection points. 
Solutions (x - coordinates of intersection points) are 1.57, 3.67, 5.76.

How to reach the solution without a graphing calculator ?

I can try equating them further;

$2 \sin(x) + 1 - 2 \sin^2(x) = 2 \sin^2(x) - 1$

$2\sin x - 2\sin^2(x) - 2\sin^2(x) = -2$

$ 2 \sin x - 4\sin^2(x) = - 2 $

$ \sin x - 2 \sin^2(x) = -1 $

If I put this equation in my scientific calculator I get -0.52. I have no idea how to get those three intersection points, it must be possible..

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for that too!

Comment: By the way I used Sin^2(x) why was it not taken as superscript ?

Comment: Nevermind figured it out haha

Comment: All math must be surrounded by `$`, inside the dollar signs  they would be super scripts: `$5^3$` makes $5^3$. Another thing is functions like $\sin$ should be written in lowercase and prefixed with a backslash, if that's not done the function is written in italics and we only want that for variables: `$\sin^2x$` which makes $\sin^2 x$. Please edit your question by clicking the edit button below your question, and read the links I posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we have $$2\sin^2x-\sin x-1=0$$

$$\implies\sin x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1^2+4\cdot2}}{2\cdot2}=\frac{1\pm3}4=1,-\frac12$$

$$\sin x=1\implies x=2n\pi+\frac\pi2$$

$$\sin x=-\frac12=-\sin\frac\pi6=\sin\left(-\frac\pi6\right)$$

$$x=r\pi+(-1)^r\left(-\frac\pi6\right)$$  where $r,n$ are integers

Comment: Okay so you assumed whole Sinx as x and solved for it, wow. I used the last equation and plugged 1 and 2 in place of r I got 3.67 and 5.76 points. How do I decide what values to put in r or n ? 
Also what is the difference between the two roots and which one should be used ?

Comment: I get how this is done but if someone could actually explain how to get the intersection points it'll be a great help :T Also how is the last equation is obtained ?

Comment: @lucax, We need $0\le2n\pi+\dfrac\pi2\le2\pi\iff0\le4n+1\le4\implies n=0$

and similarly, $$0\le r\pi+(-1)^r\left(-\frac\pi6\right)\le2\pi$$

Check for even$(2m)$ & odd$(2m+1)$  values of $r$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$2\sin x=-\cos2x-(1-2\sin^2x)=-2\cos2x$$

$$\iff\cos2x=-\sin x=\cos\left(\dfrac\pi2+x\right)$$

$$\implies2x=2m\pi\pm\left(\dfrac\pi2+x\right)$$ where $m$ is any integer